# Test user input against regex with jquery

Tags: html, jquery

I have a field where a user can submit any kind of information, but I want to invalidate submissions which contain any of my blacklist keywords which I've placed in a regex. If the user was to submit a phrase like "Are you interested in marketing?", then it should return the alert which says "this is spam". I've been searching for hours, but I can't find what the problem is with this script:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var user_input = $(":input[name=input_4]"); 
    var spam_check = user_input.val().search(/\b(marketing|dating|sexy)\b/i); 
    user_input.change(function() {
        if (spam_check !== -1) {
            alert("This is spam");
        }
    });  
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this line:

```
var spam_check = user_input.val().search(/\b(marketing|dating|sexy)\b/i);
```

**INSIDE** the `.change` function. Like below:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var user_input = $(":input[name=input_4]"); 
    user_input.change(function() {
        var spam_check = user_input.val().search(/\b(marketing|dating|sexy)\b/i); 
        if (spam_check !== -1) {
            alert("This is spam");
        }
    });  
});
```

Because you need to check the `val()` after change not before.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! 
I can't believe it was that simple the whole time ‍♂️